# Quantum-airy operators to specialised ones

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, vertex-algebras

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite or countable dimension over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $n$ denote the dimension of $V$ and the index set $I=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$($n$ tend to $\infty$). Let us choose an order basis on $V$ and denote it by $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$. Denote $y^{1},\ldots,y^{n}$, the dual basis corresponding to $x_{i}$. The vector space $W:=T^{*}(V^{*})=V\oplus V^{*}$, we have the standard symplectic structure. The corresponding Possion bracket are given by
$\{x_{i},y^{j} \}=\delta_{ij}$, $\{x_{i},x_{j}\}=0$, $\{y^{i},y^{j}\}=0$.

Quantum airy structure on $V$ is given by a collection of at most quadratic (i.e. elements of $Sym_{\leq 2}(W)$) of the form,
\begin{equation}
L_{i}:= \hbar\partial^{i}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{cd}A^{icd}x_{c}x_{d}-\sum_{cd}\hbar B_{c}^{id}\partial^{c}x_{d}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{cd}\hbar^{2}C_{cd}^{i}\partial^{c}\partial^{d}-\hbar D^{i},
\end{equation}
such that the vector space $\oplus_{1\leq i \leq n } k\ L_{i}$ is closed under the lie bracket. $A,B,C,D$ are constant.

The important theorem is that for any quantum airy structure, there exists a unique solution $\mathcal{Z}^{KS}(x)$ to the collection of
differential constraints $L_{k}\mathcal{Z}^{KS}=0, k\in I$ of the following form:
\begin{equation} \label{PartitionfuncKS}
\mathcal{Z}^{KS}(x)=\exp\Big(\sum_{\substack{g\geq 0, n\geq 1\\ 2g-2+n >0 }}\frac{h^{2g-2+n}}{n!}\sum_{(\alpha_1 ,\ldots , \alpha_n) \in I^{n}}F_{g,n}[\alpha_1 ,  \ldots \alpha_n ]x_{\alpha_{1}}\cdots x_{\alpha_{n}}\Big)\quad(*)
\end{equation}

Now the collection $L_i$ could be finite or infinite.

My question begin from here. So I aim to study the generating function

\begin{equation} 
\label{onept}
\mathcal{Z}_{onept}^{KS}(x)=\exp\Big(\sum_{\substack{g\geq 0,\\ 2g-1 >0 }}h^{2g-1}\sum_{\alpha_1  \in I}F_{g,n}[\alpha_1 ]x_{\alpha_{1}}\Big)\quad (**)
\end{equation}

I propose the following way we derive (*) from (**).
we introduce a parameter $s$ alongside $x$. Hence
$$ 
\mathcal{Z}_{onept}^{KS}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\mathcal{Z}^{KS}(sx)\Bigg\lfloor_{s=0}
$$

I want to know what would be the corresponding $L_i^{onept}$ such that
$$L_i^{onept} \mathcal{Z}_{onept}^{KS}(x)=0 $$ is this obtained by the change of coordinate we did to derive (**) from (*)?
Now if we specialise $x_a = x^a$ we get a finite ODE?

Comment: For QUANTUM Airy structures, the linear span of the $L_i$'s shall be closed under the commutator of differential operators (rather than under the Poisson bracket, which rather appears in the definition of CLASSICAL Airy structures).

Comment: Oh thanks, I will change it.